# Toolbar isn't tinting MenuItems

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I have some white-on-transparent icons I want to use in my Toolbar, but they aren't being tinted to fit my theme (based on `AppCompat.Light`). No matter what color icons I put, they stay that color and don't turn dark gray (like the overflow and SearchView icons do).

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
```

Here's my theme:

```
<style name="Theme.*myapp*" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/accent_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/*myapp*.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#DE000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#8A000000</item>
</style>
```

Is there something I have to do to get the Toolbar to tint MenuItems?

Comment: these feature works only on android lollipop. whats the API level of your device ?

Comment: 21. Lollipop preview on my Nexus 7, as well as on the emulator.

Comment: And your Nexus7 runs Lollipop?

Comment: Yes, the Nexus 7 runs Lollipop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this        `<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>`

Comment: Try add this to you app theme. Not ToolBar theme only. But then all your widets will be tinted.

Comment: I did. Didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google is hiding something:
I've tried adding this following two items to my menu.xml:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/menu_test2"
        android:icon="@drawable/i_cccc_mtrl_alpha"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        pressreader:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_test3"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        pressreader:showAsAction="always" />
```

i_cccc_mtrl_alpha is copy of abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha, abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha is from appcompat package.
So abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha works perfectly on both themes (Light & Dark) on all devices, i_cccc_mtrl_alpha is not tinted and always white...

Comment: Interesting! Not really an answer though.

Comment: I'd added as comment if I could, not enough reputation :(